# How to implement different hover effect for the links as shown in the code?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

In the code, there are two links and I want to implement different hover effects for both the links (i.e if I hover over `I want to buy` the link should become `red` and if I hover over the link `I want to sell` It should become `blue`). Please guide me on how I could achieve it

Here is the part of the code:

```
<ul>
   <li><Link to='/buyer'>I want to buy</Link></li>
   <li><Link to='/seller'>I want to sell</Link></li>
</ul>
```

In case if I used an anchor tag I could have used `a: hover` but was unable to find what to do in the above case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define class name to the `<li>` tag, then by using CSS [Descendant Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) (a whitespace), you can reach the `<a>` tag:

```
.classNameOfLiTag a:hover {
  // styling
}
```

Descendant selector can select any descendant elements wrapped under `<li>` regardless how deep. To be more precise, you can use child selector (>) that selects only `<a>` tag that is directly the children of `<li>` like so:

```
.classNameOfLiTag > a:hover {
  // styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your js file:

```
<ul>
   <li><Link to='/buyer' className={class1}>I want to buy</Link></li>
   <li><Link to='/seller' className={class2}>I want to sell</Link></li>
</ul>
```

In your css:

```
.class1:hover {
       color: red;
}

.class2:hover {
       color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add different class to li and then give it hover styles

```
 <ul>
   <li className="link1"><Link to='/buyer'>I want to buy</Link></li>
   <li className="link2"><Link to='/seller'>I want to sell</Link></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.link1:hover{
// your style
}
.link1:hover{
// your style
}
```